# If your body can slow down your metabolism, why doesn't it do that all the time?

Tags: metabolism

I've read that in cases such as in anorexia or a lack of food, the body slows down the metabolism to preserve the little food it does get. If it can do this, though, why doesn't it keep your metabolism slowed, preserving energy? Are there effects to slowing down your metabolism?

Edit: I read it in various realistic fiction books about anorexia, which claimed to have accurate medical information. One was *Wintergirls*, by Laurie Halse Anderson, where the girl with anorexia says she has a slow metabolism, and her doctor mother says something to the effect of "your body's slowed down your metabolism because it thinks you're in a famine."

Comment: Low metabolis-> Low ATP. ATP is needed for activity so more activity-> Need of more ATP. Since we didn't need to be very slow like a sloth , therefore our metabolism is not less always.

Comment: If I have time to answer I will... but the short answer is that when your body "slows down" metabolism in times of starvation or famine, that also halts growth and reproductive functions as well. Maximal growth and reproduction require an individual with sufficient energy stores.